# Why am I not able to access an image from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgExpCol" AlternateText="plus" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/theImages/subTaskPlus.png" runat="server" CssClass="imgExpCol" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubTasks" runat="server" CssClass="pnlSubTasks" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSubTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Task Name" HeaderText="Task Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/theImages/Dependencies.png" CssClass="gvTaskDep btnShowDepend" runat="server" ID="btnShowDepend" OnCommand="btnShowDepend_Command" CommandName="TaskDepend" AlternateText='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' ToolTip="Click to view Dependencies" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Site" HeaderText="Site" SortExpression="Site" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Practice" HeaderText="Practice" SortExpression="Practice" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Provider" HeaderText="Provider" SortExpression="Provider" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Roles" HeaderText="Roles" SortExpression="Roles" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Object" HeaderText="Object" SortExpression="Object" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideTag" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideTag" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FK" HeaderText="FK" SortExpression="Object" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideTag" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideTag" />
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I try to access `imgExpCol` from code-behind, it cannot find it.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: How are you trying to access? In which event?

Comment: Please show your event handler code.

Comment: `imgExpCol` is created inside the Item Template meaning there (may) be multiple instances of that control on the page. Which one were you expecting it to refer to? Or are you finding it relative to the control which raised the event?

Comment: It is just used once

Comment: You did not post the code used to find the Image. That's highly relevant and should be included in your question.

Comment: Largely irrelevant. The item template is not part of the page itself, it's a template that's used when objects are created. The fact that you're choosing to create only one doesn't mean .Net can assume there's only ever going to be one instance. Hence you can't just refer to the control by name, you need to "find" it. Can you please show how you're trying to access it in your code behind?

Comment: If you're truly "searching for knowledge", then I'd listen to what @Basic is saying. Just because there is only a single row in your GridView control does not mean that you can just look for the control directly, you need to look for the control WITHIN the instance created for the single GridView row

Answer (score 2):

Since item templates are created at runtime, you won't have access to them.  Try something like

```
var imgExpCol= yourTasksGV.FindControl("imgExpCol") as Image;
```

Comment: That one I  have no issue with. It is the `imgExpCol` image that I cannot access.

Comment: Same thing.  Just change it to:
var imgExpCol = yourTasksGV.FindControl("imgExpCol") as Image;

Comment: `var iExpCol = yourTasksGV.FindControl("imgExpCol") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image;
     if (iExpCol != null)
     {
      MessageBox.Show("hide");
     }` It seems like the image is NULL :/

Answer (score 2):

As KidBilly says, you cannot access them directly. Also, be aware that their IDs will be mangled at runtime since it is not permitted to have multiple IDs that are the same on a single page (i.e. one button for each row of your GridView), in which case, you will need to see how they are mangled before you know what to pass to FindControl().

For instance, I have a LinkButton with id="edit" and when it is rendered, it becomes id="MainContent_LoginView2_existingAccounts_edit_0"

Comment: I used `ClientIDMode="Static"` to avoid that

Comment: But it is not permitted to have more than one ID that is the same, this will cause all manner of problems. You could use Predictable for ClientIDMode so it still appends the rowid to the end of it.